# elasticsearch parent child extremely inefficient has_child query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a parent-child relationship in an ES index. The distribution in terms of the number of documents is around 20% for the parents (200M docs) and 80% children (1B docs). ES cluster has 5 nodes, each with 20GB RAM and 4 CPU cores. ES version is 1.5.2. We use 5 shards per index and 0 replication.

When I query it using the `has_child`, the processing is extremely slow - 170 sec. However, when I just run over the parents it takes less than a second.

This query takes far too long to return and causes timeouts within the application. I really care about the aggregations and time range filter.

I believe what is happening is that the query is running over every child first to do the filtering. In reality, I only would like it to run over the parents first and check if there is a single document and then use filter on the children.

#### Setup

The `_parent` is an action that looks like this

```
{
     "a": "m_field",
     "b": "b_field",
     "c": "c_field",
     "d": "d_field"
}
```

The `_child` is a timestamp when that action has occurred

```
{
     "date": "2016-07-07T11:11:11Z"
}
```

These are typically stored in time series indices. Indexes are sharded by a month. An index usually takes around 70GB total size on disk. We choose to run it over an alias, which combines all or some of the most recent indices.

#### Query

When I query I do a `query_string` on the `_parent` document to search for the `keyword` and a `Range` filter on the child, using the `has_child` query.

This looks like the following.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": { 
     "base_aggs": {
        "cardinality": {
           "field": "a"
        }
      }
  },
  "query": {
     "bool": {
       "must": [
       {
          "filtered": {
             "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "*",
                    "fields": [
                       "a",
                       "b",
                       "c",
                       "d",
                       "e"
                    ],
                    "default_operator": "and",
                    "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
                    "lowercase_expanded_terms": true
                 }
              },
              "filter": {
                 "has_child": {
                    "type": "evt",
                    "min_children": 1,
                    "max_children": 1,
                    "filter": {
                       "range": {
                          "date": {
                             "lte": "2016-07-06T23:59:59.000",
                             "gte": "2016-06-07T00:00:00.000"
                          }
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "must_not": [
          {
             "term": {
                "b": {
                   "value": ""
                }
             }
          },
          {
             "term": {
                "b": {
                  "value": "__"
             }
          }
        }
      ] 
    }
  }
}
```

So the query should match on my `query_string` with the entry "*" and have children that are between the two dates provided. Because I only care about the aggregations I do not return any documents, and I only need to match on a single child document.

#### Question

How can I improve the speed of the query?

Answer (score 0):

> The performance of a `has_child` query or filter with the `min_children`
>   or `max_children` parameters is much the same as a `has_child` query with
>   scoring enabled.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/has-child.html#min-max-children

So I guess, you would have to drop those parameters to speed up the query.

Comment: Unfortunately removing the min/max children parameters doesn't speed it up. I assumed I could set that so that it could be included in the aggregation if there are 1 or more child documents that matched. But it still exhibits the same behavior whether it is included or not.

Comment: Could you try changing the evt range "filter" with the range "query"?